# Running any React-Native project for iOS results in 'Unable to resolve module' error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying out the much hyped React-Native as an alternative to native development. I have installed nvm, react, react-native, and the cli by following this [guide](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-installing-react-native/).

I have tried downloading and running several projects from github but no project has ever run (navigate to project directory, npm install then react-native run-ios) successfully. I usually get this error: 'Unable to resolve module'.

The error mentions it may be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968. It also provides some solutions, non of which have ever worked. Reinstalling the node modules never works, neither does resetting the cache. I have also tried reinstalling react, rn, and the cli. The last 'solution' is to recreate the project from scratch, which I haven't tried thus far.

The emperor has no clothes.

P.S Even the example iOS project in the react-native github repo throws errors (albeit different ones: No script URL provided.)

Comment: I highly recommend trying to downgrade your version of react native to 0.50.1. I recently tried upgrading and ran into that issue. Not sure what is going on there, but the last 4-5 minor updates have not been as stable as they have been in the past.

Comment: Hey Paul, this doesn't work for me.